# how to solve select Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello everyone there is an issue in select query. the scenario is i have two table one is `Customerprofile` and `propertyalloted`. i want to select only those `customer name` which are not present in `propertyalloted` table.

here is my query please tell me change in my existing query

```
select distinct 
    (a.ApplicationNo),
    a.Serial,
    b.Name,
    a.CustomerName,
    Convert(varchar(10),a.DOB,103) as DOB ,
    a.Nationality,
    a.Age,
    a.Profession,
    a.Password,                   
    a.ResidentialStatus,
    a.PanNo,
    a.MailingAdd1,
    a.MailingAdd2,
    a.TelNo,
    a.MobileNo,
    a.FaxNo,
    a.OfficeAdd1,
    a.CusId,                      
    a.OfficeAdd2,
    a.OfficeTel,
    a.OfficeFax,
    a.EMail,
    a.SO,
    a.PassportNo,
    a.CustPicture                        
 from CustomerProfile a,FranchiseProfile b                        
 where  a.FranchiseId=b.FId
```

Comment: you could use not-exists,not-in,left joins/is-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given tables in your query as:  `CustomerProfile , FranchiseProfile` but in question description as: `registered and propertyalloted.` Also as you applied a cross join if you are looking just for something like: Select all customer names from `CustomerProfile` table which are not in FranchiseProfile table then adding a subquery like below might help:

```
 select a.CustomerName  
 from  CustomerProfile a,FranchiseProfile b                        
 where a.FranchiseId=b.FId 
 and  a.CustomerName  not in (select c.Name from FranchiseProfile c)
```

Comment: actually that registered table is customerprofile table, i have written by mistake

Comment: Did above query helped you or you have conditions to be applied while fetching out data from the two tables?

Comment: Please select an answer for your question in case your query has been resolved..:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM table1 lt
                   WHERE lt.customer_name = t.customer_name)
```

Using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.customer_name NOT IN (SELECT lt.customer_name
                             FROM table1 lt)
```

using `joins`

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.customer_name
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT  JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```